# How can I find a tag/way in another way/area with Overpass?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I want all industries in "Chemnitz" with a "hot_water_tank".

This query gives me all objects with tags `"landuse"="industrial"` and `"man_made"="hot_water_tank"`. I need only the `"landuse"="industrial"` containing a `"hot_water_tank"`.

```
area
  ["name"="Chemnitz"]->.a;        
out body qt;
(
  way
    (area.a)                   
    ["landuse"="industrial"];

    way(area.a)
   ["man_made"="hot_water_tank"];


);

out body qt;

>;

out skel qt;
```

i tried this

```
area
  ["name"="Chemnitz"]->.a;        

(
  way
    (area.a)                   
    ["landuse"="industrial"]->.c;
    way(area.a)
   ["man_made"="hot_water_tank"]->.s;

  (.c; .s;)->.all;
  (.c; - .s;)->.I_without_T;
  (.s; - .c;)->.T_wihtout_I;
  ((.all; - .I_without_T;) - .T_without_I;);


);

out body qt;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Screenshots of the results:

[image: here a industry with tanks, now i need only the industry with tanks]
[image: the dark red point is the industry with hot_water_tanks, i need only a result with the industry]

Comment: cross-posted: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/52369/how-to-query-a-way-containing-a-specific-way-overpass-api

Comment: do you have an answer? isnt it allowed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here was to use two little known statements from Overpass QL. 
First **is_in** gives us areas in which features are located, second we need to extract relations and/or ways from said areas using **pivot**.

Here is a sample code:

```
(area["name"="Chemnitz"]) -> .chemnitz; //Chemnitz

(
  way(area.chemnitz)["man_made"="hot_water_tank"];
  (._;>;)
)->.hotwatertank; // all tanks in Chemnitz

(.hotwatertank is_in;) -> .areas; // areas in which tanks are located

(
  way(pivot.areas)["landuse"="industrial"];
  relation(pivot.areas)["landuse"="industrial"];
)->._; // convert areas to ways and relations with "landuse"="industrial" pair

(._;._ >;); // get geometry
out body qt; //print
```